# PowerApp Portals - CORS

Tags: cors, powerapps, powerapps-portal

How to allow CORS in the PowerApp portal?

I have an Ajax request that fetches some data from an API but the request is being blocked because there is CORS policy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there may be a way to do it, but it may take a bit of work if your desired API doesn't meet the requirements.  [Check out this post](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/hr-hr/blog/register-and-use-custom-apis-in-powerapps/) related to registering a customer data source/API.